# How to handwrite these characters in hangul

Tags: written

how do you handwrite (stroke order) the following syllabels in korean:

1) 농

2) 협

3) 햅

4) 쌀

5) 사

6) 용

Is there any reference that shows a complete database on how to handwrite (the stroke order) of "hangul syllabels" instead of just the stroke order of Korean "hangul letters"?

Comment: Take a look at this answer about stroke order: https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/3225/206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database of the stroke orders for all of the Hangul syllables would contain a huge amount of redundant data.  There are just 24 letters, but there are approx 11,000 different syllables that you can make with those letters (only 2,000-3,000 of which are actually used).

> The number of the theoretically possible Modern Hangul syllables in Unicode is: 11,172. Among these, the top 2350 syllables occupy 99.9% of all that is used.
>
> Initial consonant 19 * Middle vowel 21 * (Final consonant 27 + No final 1) = 11,172.
>
> Among these, there are 3.192 possible syllable combinations possible in Korean phonotactics:
>
> Initial consonant 19 * Middle vowel 21 * (Final consonant 7 + No final 1) = 3,192.

*From [Karavinka on the UniLang Language Community Forum](https://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?t=24384#p463408)*

A database is not necessary.  You can easily memorize the stroke order for 24 letters.  This related answer has good information on the stroke order for those 24 letters: [Hangul — printed vs handwritten](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/3225/206)

Since you're asking specifically about syllables, perhaps the missing piece of information is how to take those letters and compose them into syllables.  [How to Study Korean Unit 0 Lesson 1](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit0/unit0lesson1/) has some good illustrations and explanations of this.